# How to access field value in a JSR-303 message?

Tags: spring, field, bean-validation, substitution

I would like to customize my error message in the following way:

Assume following declaration of a class Person:

```
@Size(min=10, max=200, message="{name.size}")  
private String name;
```

Within the declared error message in ValidationMessages.properties I would like to output the field value as well, i.e. I would like to do something like this:

```
name.size=The name '{name}' is invalid, its size must be between {min} and {max}
```

Assume the content of the field 'name' is “abc”. Then the error message should look like this:

*The name 'abc' is invalid, its size must be between 10 and 200*

The substitution for min and max works, but how can I do this for the field value?

Answer (score 6):

With BeanValidation 1.0 I think there is a way to get the value using a message interpolater.  I believe with the hibernate implementation of bean validation 1.0 this was available as part of their bundle.

With BeanValidation 1.1 this became available via EL expressions.  The field value is now accessible via the name validatedValue.  If you could try to use the latest version.  Your message would look like this:

```
name.size=The name '${validatedValue}' is invalid, its size must be between {min} and {max}
```

Comment: this was a very good hint.

I upgraded from Spring 3.x to 4.x.

Then I added/upgraded to the following artifacts:

    javax.el
    javax.el-api
    2.2.5
    
    org.glassfish.web
    javax.el
    2.2.6
    
    javax.validation
    validation-api
    1.1.0.Final
    
    org.hibernate
    hibernate-validator
    5.1.0.Final

Comment: Let me share another issue related to this one: I am using spring and inside my custom validator implementation I am using the autowire feature. From a Junit case I am first validating directly and then I persist the entity which gets again validated by the entity manager. When validating directly autowire works inside the custom validator but it works not when invoked indirectly via entity manager. To make this working you have to specify Spring's LocalValidatorFactoryBean via the javax.persistence.validation.factory property for the EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: I havent had any issues myself with this scenario, but I don't use Spring, I just stick to out of the box JEE

Comment: It works fine for me with Hibernate Validator 5.0.2.Final. I've been looking for this for quite some time and didn't think it was possible... It's quite hard to find in the documentation.